# ngDialog - how to close dialog from the template (i.e. no controller functions)?

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

On ngDialog (https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog), is there a built in way to close a dialog from within the template it self? I.e. so I don't need any functions in the controller calling the dialog?

This is my template (errorPopup.html):

```
<div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <div class="errorLogo"><i class="icon-exclaim"></i></div>
    <div class="errorContent" data-ng-bind-html="errorMessage"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary pull-right">
      <span res="close"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I open the dialog:

```
function showErrorPopup() {
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'errorPopup.html',
    scope: $scope,
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default ngdialog-cart-theme',
    showClose: true,
    appendTo: 'div[ui-view]',
    closeByDocument: false
  });
}
```

So when I call showErrorPopup() I get a dialog displayed, however, I need to make this "close" button to actually dismiss/close the popup. As of now, this is just a plan button that doesn't do anything.

Is there something I can do a the template level (without changing my controller's code) to make the button work?

Maybe I should be using a default button instead of my own? If so, how?

PS: I notice thats clicking on the X button on the top right works, the popup is dismissed.

Thanks all!

Comment: It closes the window, but doesn't feel right. What would feel right then?

Comment: @AlonEitan I've rephrased my question, all I'm trying to do is figure out how do I close the dialog from within the template (without a function in the controller)

Comment: so just do `$scope.ngDialog = ngDialog;` in the controller, and in the view `ng-click="ngDialog.close()"`

Comment: @AlonEitan thats a pretty good idea actually! Might want to post it as an asnwer :D

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I have posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call the close function of the `ngDialog` directly from the view, you must inject the module itself to the scope inside the controller, in order for it to become available from the view:

```
$scope.ngDialog = ngDialog;
```

Then, you can use it directly from within the view:

```
<button ng-click="ngDialog.close()">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

You don`t have to inject ngDialog module in your $scope. You can call closeThisDialog() function in your popup template directly:

```
<button ng-click="closeThisDialog(0)">Close</button>
```

function argument is the value to resolve popup with.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say what exactly you are doing wrong, until you paste some controller and app.js and HTML code contents. 
**Yes, ngDialog has built-in way of closing the dialog**

Make Sure you set the className to 'ngdialog-theme-flat ngdialog-theme-custom' or other css class as described in the docs inside open function.

Answer (score 0):

You have added handler with name **"closeThisDialog"** , but function has another name **"closePopup"**.

Maybe it is your issue.

Comment: Thx but you probably just got confused with my question. I've rephrased it to avoid this exact mix up :D

Answer (score 0):

just follow these steps
1.when creating app

`var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngDialog']);`
2.use button like this

```
<button ng-click="clickMe()">Click to Open</button>
```

3.put this in your controller

```
 `$scope.clickMe = function () {
    ngDialog.open();
};`
```

by default it has code to close,It'll close automatically when you click on close.
Hope it'll be useful

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The problem I have is that I reuse the template on multiple pages and that would mean I'd have to have this clickMe function on every sone one of my controllers...